# Folland Real Analysis 7.3

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $X$ be the one-point compactification of a set with the discrete topology. If $\mu$ is a Radon measure on $X$, then supp($\mu$) is countable.

So if I let $X^*$ be the one-point compactification (which I assume is $X \cup \left\lbrace \infty \right\rbrace $), then my topological space is $(X^*, P(X^*))$.

I know two things about the support of $\mu$ from a previous homework problem:

1) $supp(\mu)$ is the complement of $N$ where $N$ is the union of all open $U \in X^*$ with $\mu(U) = 0$.

2) $x \in supp(\mu)$ iff $\int f d\mu > 0$ for every $f \in C_c(X^*, [0,1])$ such that $f(x) > 0$

However, neither of those seem to suggest anything about the countability of the support.  I suppose if I could show there are only countably many $x \in supp(\mu)$ so that condition 2 holds, then that would work. But I don't see any way to do such a thing. Condition 1 seems easier to work with but doesn't seem to involve countability at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mu $ is Radon on the compactification $X $ (which is compact!). Hence, it is a finite measure.

Let $A = \rm {supp}(\mu) $ and let $X_0$ be the set of which $X $ is the compactification. Now, for $x \in A \cap X_0$, we have $\mu (\{x\})>0$, since otherwise,  $B := A \setminus \{x\} $ would be a closed(!) proper subset of $X $ with $\mu (B^c)=0$. This uses $\mu (A^c)=0$.

Now, we have shown
$$
A \cap X_0 =  \bigcup_n \{x \in A \cap X_0 \mid \mu (\{x\})> 1/n\}
$$
and since $\mu $ is finite, so is each set in the union. This easily shows that $A $ is countable.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have a question or two for you about this for my understanding. 1) Can you explain what "let $X_0$ be the set of which $X$ is the compactification" means? I don't really understand what a one-point compactification is because it looks like the $A \cap X_0$ means we've shown a subset of $A$ is countable when we want to show $A$ is. 2) Why is it bad if $B$ is closed? I guess I don't see why that forces $\mu(\left\lbrace x \right\rbrace) >0$. Sorry, I really struggle with this subject.

Comment: 1) We have $X = X_0 \cup \{\infty\} $ (or $X =X_0$ if $X_0$ is compact to begin with) so $A $ contains at most one more point that $A \cap X_0$. Ad 2) It is good (for our contradiction) that $B $ is closed. By writing "closed (!)", I just wanted you to convince yourself that it really is (since $\{x\} $ is open). We have $\mu (B^c) = \mu (A^c) + \mu (\{x\})=0$ in case of $\mu (\{x\})=0$. But then $B $ is a strict closed subset of the support of $\mu $ such that the complement has measure zero. But the support is the smallest such set.

Comment: Point 1 makes sense to me. For point 2, I think I'm still struggling to see why $B$ being closed is useful. I understand why it's closed, but not why it's important it's closed (I'm really sorry for my ignorance of this subject). Does it have to do with the support being closed?

Comment: @Brenton:  Yes. What I am using its that by definition, the support is the smallest closed set such that the complement has measure zero. Equivalently, the complement is the largest open set with measure zero.

Comment: So after writing it out carefully, I finally understand! Last question: Why is it necessary that $\mu$ is finite and each set in the union is as well? I thought you just need to write the set $A \cap X_0$ as a countable union and that's it.

Comment: @Brenton: If $\mu$ is not finite, you won't be able to show that $M_n := \{x \in A \cap X_0 \mid \mu(\{x\}) > 1/n\}$ is finite. What we use here is that $\infty > \mu(X) \geq \mu(M_n) \geq \sum_{x \in F} \mu(\{x\}) \geq |F|/n$ for every finite (or countable) subset $F \subset M_n$ and hence $|F| \leq n \cdot \mu(X)$. Since this holds for every finite subset, $M_n$ must be finite. One can modify this proof to still work if $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite. But in general, it won't work.

Comment: I think my question must've been unclear, sorry about that. Why do you need $M_n$ to be finite?

Comment: Since then,  $A \cap X_0 = \bigcup_n M_n $ will be countable as a countable union of finite (hence countable) sets. If one of the $M_n $ was uncountable,  this would not work.

Comment: So when we say something is countable, it has to be union of not only countably many sets, but also each set is of finite measure?

Comment: @Brenton: Every countable union of countable sets is countable. But not every countable union of arbitrary sets is countable (otherwise, everything would be countable). This has nothing to do with measure. The concept of measure only enter when we want to show (in our special case) that each $M_n$ is countable (actually finite).

Comment: Can you please elaborate the fact that why $M_n=\{x\in A\cap X_0 | ~\mu(\{x\})>\frac{1}{n} \}$ will have finite measure.

Comment: @bunny: $X$ is compact (as the compactification of $X_0$), and $\mu$ is a Radon measure on $X$. But Radon measures are required (at least according the definition that I know and use) to give finite measure to compact sets. Hence, $\mu(X) < \infty$, so that **every** (measurable) set has finite $\mu$-measure.